# Fourier series - showing that an expression is true

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have this function: 
$f(t) = \frac{1}{12} (\pi^2 t-t^3)$ and I have a Fourier series defined by:

$$f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3} \sin (nt)$$

I am then suppose to show that this is true:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6} = \frac{\pi^6}{945}$$

I tried doing something like this a few times where you just have to input a $t$ where the function is continuous (like $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or something like that), but I just cant seem to figure out a $t$ that makes this true.. Are there other ways of doing it?

Comment: Are you sure your Fourier series solution is correct? (I haven't tried it, I just wanted to make sure so I didn't have to do the computation myself).

Comment: Assume the Fourier series is correct (which I didn't check), try using Parseval's formula (you may know it as Plancherel's formula).

Comment: The fourier series solution is correct, yes - and thank you, I'll give that a try :)